# Make a reliable counter in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I want to create a counter in an application written in PHP using a MySQL database. The user gives a string as input. This string represents the key to a database record. It stores a integer counter value. The user gets back the incremented value.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
// connect to database
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo "DB Error: ".$ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// update and get new value
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $nc = updateNC($db, $grundsig, $library);
    $db->commit();
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    $db->rollBack();
    $err = 'DB Error: '.$ex->getMessage();
}

// [...]

function updateNC($db, $grundsig, $library) {

    // increment counter ("nc")
    $query = $db->prepare('
        update numeruscurrens n
        join libraries l using(libid)
        set n.nc = n.nc+1
        where n.grundsig = :grundsig and l.libname = :libname
    ');
    $query->execute([
        ':grundsig' => $grundsig,
        ':libname' => $library
    ]);

    // get new counter value
    $query = $db->prepare('
        select *
        from numeruscurrens n
        join libraries l using(libid)
        where n.grundsig = :grundsig and l.libname = :libname
    ');
    $query->execute([
        ':grundsig' => $grundsig,
        ':libname' => $library
    ]);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    return $result[0]['nc'];
}
```

The important part happens in `updateNC` function. I do a update to increment the counter and I want to have the new counters value.

Now the problem is between these two commands another user could do a update. It could happen that two users get wrong counter values.

How can I reliably increment a counter and get the new value for this user?

I also thought about using a key-value-database like Redis which has the [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr) command. But this would be a little exaggerated, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if it even make sense what you're trying. But can I ask you how many users you expect? And how big is the chance that two users enter the same key value at the same time? It should be nearly 0.

Comment: I think if there is a chance, it should be found a way to bypass it. A team of about 20 people is using these counters. And if there occurs such an error it would be a great problem. It's also nearly impossible to win the lottery but some people does.

Comment: Are they going to us this counters all seconds / minutes? Also may explain what you're trying to do / for what you want to use it. I think there are much better solutions than this one you're trying. Also, if I understand you, there will be X-counters, since you said that users can give the key to the counter? So why all member of your team has to edit all counters? Why not simply create one counter for each member, give them ONE key and everything would be fine..?

Comment: There are ~40000 counters in that DB. They are not related to a person. I added the info about the INCR command from Redis to explain more what I want. Is there some way to get this done in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to be sure they will get the immediately incremented value then you should be using a way to lock the row you are going to update before commiting the transaction. This can be done using the `FOR UPDATE` hint and a previous SELECT query to lock the row you're about to update.

I will add only the SQL code to focus on the actual problem.

```
SET @counter = 0;

BEGIN;

SELECT n.nc INTO @counter
FROM numeruscurrens n
JOIN libraries l using(libid)
WHERE n.grundsig = @grundsig and l.libname = @libname
FOR UPDATE;

update numeruscurrens n
join libraries l using(libid)
set n.nc = n.nc+1
where n.grundsig = @grundsig and l.libname = @libname

/* You are always incrementing, aren't you? */
SET @counter = @counter + 1;

SELECT @counter;

COMMIT;
```

Also notice, this is not free. It has to actually be a requirement to have this increment value properly returned to the user because this locking will have a negative impact on performance due to row locking and might create deadlocks. Last but not least, ensure the table is using the `InnoDB` engine. `MyIsam` doesn't support row-level locks.

Comment: That looks quite good. Your solution guided me to the documentation where is noticed a better way in MySQL which uses only one table access:  UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = LAST_INSERT_ID(counter_field + 1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: I didn't know that one, quite neat.